I wish/If only wishful thinking
So I know that if we aim to wishfully think about present things we naturally use Past Simple after I wish/If only or Past Perfect if it's about past wishes/dreams. My question is- does it apply to all verbs following this construct? For example:

I wish she knew I love her

Should the "love" verb also be changed according to the past tense rules? What about the wish about the past?:

I wish she had known that I love her

Something tells me that in this case love should be transformed to "loved" or even "had loved"
Anybody got a rational explanation which would clarify those things?

If you loved her in the past you'd use "I wish she had known that I loved her". It's basically the same as any other back-shifting: present tense can be used for eternal truths, but normally you use past tense.
